# Publishing an Asp.Net Mvc,Web Api Application to Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I published my Asp.Net Mvc5 application to Windows Azure by following below described procedure.

```
1.  Right Click at project and select Publish
2.  I selected File System and have given it location and Published the application 
    Here is Screen Shot
```

[image]

```
3.  Then I specified Settings here is settings screenshot
```

[image]

```
4.  Then I published it and it got published to my local system without any errors.![enter image description here][3]


5.  I uploaded to Windows Azure via FileZilla using FTP.
    Uploading was also successfull.
```

6. But When i browse the url i get following error. [image]

   Kindly tell me what step i am missing However I have proper setting in App_Start Route Config which is my Home Controller and its Index Action.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Enable detailed errors to see what the actual error is. But, does your app use a database? If so, make sure that you created the DB in Azure and have the right connection strings.

Comment: Yes I have created database and uploaded it and have proper  connection string in my web.config.I have figured out one issue that is my application is using asp.net mvc5 ,web api 2 and .Net framework 4.5.1 but person who set up server went for configuring .net framework 3.5.1 that could be the reason for it.We are again configuring environment again for .net 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to publish it direct into azure ?

Its been quite a while when I published my last asp application to azure but if I remember right I published it direct to the staging environment via visual studio. May you can try it this way. I don’t know if there is a difference.. but that way worked for me ...

If you use external resource ensure that they are in your package.. -> Deployment Type

Comment: Direct deploying is not available due to my client restrictions but can you plz explain your last line a bit in more details  package--->Deployment Type

Comment: I can remember that i was trying to use a framework to create pdf files and had problems cause VS did not put this ressources into my  deployment package.  Have you tried to publish a very basic project ? Just for testing ?

Comment: No i did not tried any test project I am reading some topics over here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/introduction lets see what will happen.Thank you very much Constantin Treiber real pleasure to get your help.thank you so much

Comment: No thank needed ;-) I guess it helped not really much..  If you have a azure web-Login .. Maybe you can try this via web-Deployment
http://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy/

Comment: I am aware of such deployments I know I watched several conferences and talks at youtube they are also deploying mostly like this way as explained in this article but for my case i need to go that way by using FTP because i don't have this option i only have ftp,mstsc url  and database server etc.